# formatting an xml in vi

Tags: xml, vi

I use the following command to format my xml in vi.

```
:1,$!xmllint --format --recover - 2>/dev/null
```

However the indentation is not proper . The output is like the data inside a tag are seperated by 1 spaces  .

```
   <masterTag>                     
      <tag1>eeww</tag1>  
      <tag2>rrt</tag2>             
      <tag3>ee</tag3>      
      <tag4>1</tag4>                   
    </masterTag>
```

If i wish that inside a tag the  variables are seperated by 10 spaces what comamnd can i use 
ie output is

```
   <masterTag>                     
                <tag1>eeww</tag1>  
                <tag2>rrt</tag2>             
                <tag3>ee</tag3>      
                <tag4>1</tag4>                   
    </masterTag>
```

ALso there is a 4 level case requirement (input )

```
       <a>
       <b>
       <c>
       <d>
       </d>

       </c>
<!-- this is test  -->

       </b>
       </a>
```

the output i get is

```
   <a>
          <b>
                 <c>
                        <d>
   </d>
                 </c>
                 <!-- this is test  -->
          </b>
   </a>
```

which is wrong for obvious reason

Answer (score 2):

From the xmllint manual: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint

> `--format`
>
> Reformat and reindent the output. The XMLLINT_INDENT environment variable controls the indentation. The default value is two spaces " ".

Therefore the following command:

```
:1,$!XMLLINT_INDENT='          ' xmllint --format --recover - 2>/dev/null
```

will set your spacing to 10 spaces.

Using the `export` command you could changes these settings for all calls to `xmllint` in the same shell:

```
export XMLLINT_INDENT='          '
```

Comment: @retro some of my tags are 4 level deep . The command is concatenating al tags  after 2 levels  .

Comment: try to update your question with this requirement. Giving a complete example stating the expected behavior when it comes to these 4 level cases.

Comment: I added the part in question

Comment: @MAG thanks, I can reproduce the issue that you are describing but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: --recover - 2>/dev/null, what is this for?